# Polar histrogram similar to R

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm trying to do a plot similar to this one (made in R apparently) but in Matlab:

Several histograms (and not bar plot) organise around a circle
[image]

My data could be represented by M groups with N data and the length of N being different for each group. I would like M histograms around a circle to visualise them together in a nice way.

```
Group1 = rand(1,20); Hist1 = hist(Group1)
Group2 = rand(1,10); Hist2 = hist(Group2)
Group3 = rand(1,40); Hist3 = hist(Group3)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Here you can find a tour that explains how to create a good question. :-)
https://stackoverflow.com/tour
Please try to provide an example of what have you done and we will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar with [`polarhistogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarhistogram.html);

[image: polar histogram]

The code below will not be very general, but it will help you to get your hands on it:

```
N1 = 20; Group1 = rand(1,N1);
N2 = 10; Group2 = rand(1,N2);
N3 = 40; Group3 = rand(1,N3);

M = 3; % Number of groups
aWidth = 2*pi/M; % Area width in unit circle for each group

% Remap data values to area
Group1 = Group1*aWidth + 0*aWidth;
Group2 = Group2*aWidth + 1*aWidth;
Group3 = Group3*aWidth + 2*aWidth;

polarhistogram(Group1, N1/5, 'FaceColor','red',    'BinLimits', [0 1]*aWidth); hold on;
polarhistogram(Group2, N2/5, 'FaceColor','blue',   'BinLimits', [1 2]*aWidth);
polarhistogram(Group3, N3/5, 'FaceColor','green',  'BinLimits', [2 3]*aWidth);
legend('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3');
```